# .gitattributes export-ignore if in current directory but include if in subdirectory

Tags: git, deployment, web-deployment, gitattributes

How can I use .gitattributes to ignore a directory in the parent but include the directory in the child?

For example, consider a `/config` directory.  The root has a `/config` directory and there is also one located in `/app/config`

Adding

```
config export-ignore
```

would solve things for the root `/config` but it also removes the subdirectory `/app/config`.

How can I keep the subdirectory `/app/config`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[A leading slash matches the beginning of the pathname. For example, "/*.c" matches "cat-file.c" but not "mozilla-sha1/sha1.c".](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitignore.html)